# Slic3er throws "AMF parsing requires XML::SAX"

Tags: prusa-i3, software, slic3r

When I try to open prepared `.amf` plate with some items to print, Prusa's Slic3er release throw's this error:

[image: AMF parsing requires XML::SAX]

The slicer version is 1.30 distributed for Prusa's i3 MK2 1.75 printer.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution on this? I assume you've tried reinstalling and/or updating Slic3r already, right? +1 for having to mention XML onto this list, which I never expected....

Answer (score 2):

The slic3r software is written in Perl, a programming language that can be expanded with local libraries.  XML::SAX is one such library.  CPAN is a tool which can be used to retrieve libraries from the CPAN repository (Comprehensive Perl Archive Network, I believe).

I use CPAN is something I do infrequently, so I would be doing a disservice by trying to list the steps here.  Better answers are, no doubt, on stackexchange.  Nevertheless, these may help:

From your command line, start Perl running the CPAN module, and invoke the CPAN shell (your input in **bold**):

> **perl -MCPAN -e shell**
cpan> **install XML::SAX**
cpan> ... several lines of output ...
Done!
XML::SAX is up to date (0.99).
cpan> **quit**
>

With that done, try using slic3r again.